# Unknown symbol ($\#$) for surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation, surfaces

I am doing some homework currently and I came across a symbol I don't recognise. The question itself is about the Euler characteristic of a space and various statements to prove. I don't want help with the question I just want to know what the symbol stands for.

> Let $S_1,S_2$ be two surfaces. Prove that $\chi(S_1 \# S_2 )=\chi(S_1)+\chi(S_2)-2$

My question is, what does the $\#$ in $S_1\# S_2$ mean?

Comment: It's connected sum. One removes an embedded disk from $S_1$, an embedded disk from $S_2$ and glues the two along the boundary of the removed disks. This is known to be independent of the choice of the embedded disk.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum

Comment: That solves that, thanks

Comment: Though this has nothing to do with the question, I thought I'd add that one has the general formula $\chi (M_1\# M_2)=\chi(M_1)+\chi(M_2)-\chi(S^n)$ for closed connected $n$-manifolds $M_1, M_2$.

Comment: You've ruined everything! Just kidding, I don't mind that, I can figure it out :) I just don't want, if any teacher sees this, think I am trying to cheat. Which is why I say I don't want anyone to tell me how to prove or anything.

Comment: Good attitude, @ZelosMalum. Just thought you may be interested in knowing the general fact as well.

Comment: THat it is which I do appriciate! :) Gives me something fun to prove on my freetime!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, if $M_1$, $M_2$ are connected manifolds of dimension $n$, then $M_1\# M_2$ denotes their connected sum, which is again a connected manifold of dimension $n$.